# Why is this heavily downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I've just started to get more involved in answering questions and sharing my insights on the topic.  While I see most new questions get downvoted (rightfully so), I have been surprised to see this new question receiving a lot of downvotes and I just don't see why (in part because they voted without explanation):

[Little value in unit-testing the database component](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/372460/little-value-in-unit-testing-the-database-component)

To me, it appears to be a valid, well thought out question that is on-topic. While I am very interested in these types of questions, I would like to honor the community's direction as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess here is: several community members still intermix the downvote button with an "I disagree" button. Some others here are just very trigger-happy with the downvote button. And some just downvote blindly just because others downvoted already. So I hope the OP does not take it personal - the question already got a good, upvoted answer, and this answer seems to confirm the OP's point of view. That is a much better indicator for the quality of a question than the number of downvotes it got.

Now I am wondering how many downvotes this answer will get because some people disagree to my point of view ;-)

Comment: It's really unfortunate if that's the case, as it discourages good conversations.  I could see posters like this being reluctant to ask another.

Comment: I also have the feeling that some people blindly downvote (or close-vote) any question that contains a block of code, regardless of the purpose that the code serves to the question.